.NET 8 nlog DEBUG logs cannot be turned off
When my project was upgraded to .NET 8, NLog DEBUG logs cannot be turned off, regardless of whether the LogLevel in appsettings.json is set to Information or Warning.
The package I refer to is NLog.Extensions.Logging 5.3.8.
appsettings.json:
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}

Program.cs:
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddNLog();

nlog.config:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Warn"
      internalLogFile="internal-nlog.txt">

  <!--define various log targets-->
  <targets>

    <!--write logs to file-->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="own" fileName="${basedir}/Log/${shortdate}-own.log"
                 layout="------${newline}【时间】${longdate}${newline}【线程】${threadid}${newline}【记录者】${logger}${newline}【级别】${uppercase:${level}}${newline}【内容】${message}${newline}【异常】${exception:format=tostring}${newline}------" />

    <target xsi:type="File" name="info" fileName="${basedir}/Log/${shortdate}-info.log"
                 layout="------${newline}【时间】${longdate}${newline}【线程】${threadid}${newline}【记录者】${logger}${newline}【级别】${uppercase:${level}}${newline}【内容】${message}${newline}【异常】${exception:format=tostring}${newline}------" />

    <target xsi:type="File" name="debug" fileName="${basedir}/Log/${shortdate}-debug.log"
                 layout="------${newline}【时间】${longdate}${newline}【线程】${threadid}${newline}【记录者】${logger}${newline}【级别】${uppercase:${level}}${newline}【内容】${message}${newline}【异常】${exception:format=tostring}${newline}------" />

    <target xsi:type="File" name="error" fileName="${basedir}/Log/${shortdate}-error.log"
                 layout="------${newline}【时间】${longdate}${newline}【线程】${threadid}${newline}【记录者】${logger}${newline}【级别】${uppercase:${level}}${newline}【内容】${message}${newline}【异常】${exception:format=tostring}${newline}------" />

    <target xsi:type="Null" name="blackhole" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" level="Error" writeTo="error" />
    <!--Skip Microsoft logs and so log only own logs-->
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="blackhole" final="true" />
    <logger name="System.Net.Http.HttpClient.*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="blackhole" final="true" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="own" />
    <logger name="*" level="Info" writeTo="info" />
    <logger name="*" level="Debug" writeTo="debug" />
  </rules>
</nlog>


I'm guessing you have upgraded to NLog v5, that have several breaking changes. One of them is NLog.Extensions.Logging without any filter. So the advice is to use NLog LoggingRules for doing filtering, instead of Microsoft Logging Filters.

@RolfKristensen Thank you for your reply.Through consulting the data, it is found that this is indeed the cause.Here's how to fix it.
builder.Logging.AddNLog(new NLogProviderOptions  {      RemoveLoggerFactoryFilter = false  });
